# Backtest using yahoo finance and backtest

Tags: python, finance, yfinance

I'm getting an error message when I try to run the code below. How can I change my code to provide comprehensive daily and monthly returns? I want to use this code in particular for BIST30 and BIST100. Should I modify my code for a few details?

```
\#%%
import yfinance as yf
import backtrader as bt

# Download historical data for the asset

ticker = "SASA.IS"
data = yf.download(ticker, period="max", start="2020-01-02")

# Create a Backtrader data feed from the Pandas dataframe

data = bt.feeds.PandasData(dataname=data)

# Create a Backtrader strategy

class MyStrategy(bt.Strategy):
def __init__(self):
self.data_close = self.datas\[0\].close
self.sma = bt.indicators.SimpleMovingAverage(self.datas\[0\], period=200)
self.order = None

    def next(self):
        if self.order:
            # If an order is pending, do nothing
            return
    
        if self.data_close > self.sma:
            # If the price crosses above the moving average, buy the asset
            self.order = self.buy()

# Create a Backtrader cerebro object

cerebro = bt.Cerebro()

# Add the data feed to the cerebro object

cerebro.adddata(data)

# Add the strategy to the cerebro object

cerebro.addstrategy(MyStrategy)

# Run the backtest

result = cerebro.run()

# Get the Returns analyzer

returns_analyzer = result\[0\].analyzers.returns

# Get the detailed returns

returns = returns_analyzer.get_analysis()

# Print the detailed returns

print(returns)
```

I'm attempting to use this code to view daily and monthly returns.

```
\[***100%***\*\*\]  1 of 1 completed
-

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
\<ipython-input-15-b254cc0d9b5a\> in \<module\>
39
40 # Get the Returns analyzer
\---\> 41 returns_analyzer = result\[0\].analyzers.returns
42
43 # Get the detailed returns

AttributeError: 'ItemCollection' object has no attribute 'returns'
```